# Should I use extra arraylist for efficient data operations while using Sqlite db with recyclerviews?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I hope straightforward questions.

1) I managed to get the data from Sqlite db and showing them on recyclerview. The question is for example when i click on the recyclerview items and do some operations (for example copying the content or updating) is it better to use an arraylist and get the data first when application loads then do the operations on this arraylist elements (then notifying db eventually)?

2) If there is no need for extra arraylist on onContextItemSelected() operations while clicking recyclerview item again, i ve some trouble in choosing the element and its values.

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.idshare :
            //implicit intent
            shareImplicitIntent();
            return true;
```

......

for the  shareImplicitIntent() method

```
private void shareImplicitIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Cursor cursor=WordListOpenHelper.mReadableDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM 
    diary", null);
    cursor.moveToPosition(XYZ);
    Entry_Model entry_model= new Entry_Model();
    entry_model.setmEntry(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WordListOpenHelper.KEY_ENTRY)));
    String title = entry_model.getmEntry(); ......
```

basically using cursor and getting the title of the cursor at XYZ position.

But how can I choose that XYZ position ?

Working hours on it but couldnt find a clue. Please help me.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question myself, shortly no,  for example for getting input from the user and putting them in the arraylist then doing the database operations on the arraylist  not very useful nor necessary. (Yet if your database is planned to hold only small amount of entries though you can use arraylist/linkedlists for fast CRUD manipulations on the recyclerview adapter).

For the second part of the question it s easy to copy the content of the  clicked recyclerview element by creating setonclicklistener  in the viewholder constructor of the viewholder innerclass, for example;
(note unlike in the example you dont have to use contentresolver if you dont plan to share the datas in the database with other applications)

```
itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                int pos =getAdapterPosition();
                String entry = "";
                String[] mProjection =
                        { Contract.WordList.KEY_ENTRY,    // Contract class constant for the _ID column name  };




                Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(
                        queryUri), mProjection, null, null, sortOrder);

                if (cursor != null) {
                    if (cursor.moveToPosition(pos)) {
                        int indexEntry = cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.WordList.KEY_ENTRY);
                        entry = cursor.getString(indexEntry);


                    }
                }


                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "copied entry is " + entry, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return false;
            }
        });
```